# Where should I install the DacFx for Sitecore 9.0.2?

Tags: upgrade

When upgrading to Sitecore 9.0.2, one of the prerequisites is to have  Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx) version 2016 installed so to be able to deploy the .dacpac files. Is this needed on the CMS instance or on the SQL Server machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am verifying on  9.1 [installation guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/9D9703E3C9AB4751B357CD9A762D97D9.ashx), and it is explained where it should be installed.

On 9.0.2 installation guide,  is not mention anything where it should be installed datafx.

In your case you need to install on CM,Processing,Collection and Reference Data.

[image]